# Creating Product with Properties and Photos - Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, action

I'm trying to build an online store with Laravel 5.3. I have everything working fine, but I have no idea how to realize Product creation.
Every Product (Product model) may have Properties (Property model) and some Photos (Photo model).

Actually, the problem is adding photos and properties while creating new product. Photo and Property models have "product_id" column.

How can I dynamically add photos and properties if the final product does not exist yet? Photos and properties are processed with AJAX call, to make product creation easy and more functional.

I have no idea how to deal with it.

Tables:

```
/* Photo table */
id UINT(10) INDEX KEY
filename VARCHAR(255)
width INT(10)
height INT(10)
product_id UINT(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES `id` on `products`

/* Property table */
id UINT(10) INDEX KEY
property_name_id UINT(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES `id` on `property_names`
product_id UINT(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES `id` on `products`
value VARCHAR(255)

/* Product table */
id UINT(10) INDEX KEY
... many other columns
```

Why don't I just use Prestashop or similar projects? I don't need 3/4 of their functions. It will be connected with other project, so I need to create everything from scratch.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you create the Product first and then assign the Photos and Properties to it after?

Comment: That's what I've realized today. It requires unique token for every photo and after adding product I am looking for photos with this token and just assign them. Thanks for help.